# Lookup function in multiple sheets data

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

I have multiple sheets of data and I want to make it in one sheet (All of them are in the same workbook). [Link to the excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eb4aj7uc8gzbtnt/Sample%20for%20overstack.xlsx?dl=0).

I tried to use `Hlookup` function in excel file, something like below:

```
=HLOOKUP("University",Sheet1!$A$1:$G$2, 2, FALSE).
```

But, since I have more than 100 sheets of data, I want to find a way to drag the function and auto generate the function below the 2nd row. I have tried to use indirect function by setting a reference column in front as below but cannot deal with it.

```
=HLOOKUP("University", 'INDIRECT(A3)'!$A$1:$G$2, 2, FALSE)
```

My next option is VB code. But, I am new to VB. Anybody can help on it?

[image]

Comment: Instead of `'INDIRECT(A3)'!$A$1:$G$2` try something like `INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!$A$1:$G$2")`

Comment: is there only 1 entry in each sheet?

Comment: Yes, it is only 1 entry in each sheet. But, i use your function to solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your individual sheet names in column H of the `Summary` sheet and the row number in column I (as helper columns) and write this formula in cell `A2` of the summary sheet.

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A$1,INDIRECT($H2&"!A1:G"&$I2),$I2,0),)
```

and drag to column F and down for as many sheet rows combos you have. I used 10 rows but you can obviously make it longer or shorter as neeed.

[image]

When you are done you can filter on 0 in column A and remove any lines with no data.

If your sheet names have spaces in them, you'll need to adjust the `INDIRECT` formula to this:

```
INDIRECT("'"&$H2&"'!A1:G"&$I2)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ScottCraner. Totally read over that part! I have adjusted my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, your solution did help me, especially the IFERROR function which remind me on the setting if error function. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

best way would be "defined names" + `INDIRECT` + `HLOOKUP` (or `LOOKUP`) like:

```
defined names
name:    SList
formula: =MID(TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1))&T(NOW()),FIND("]",TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1))&T(NOW()))+1,255)
```

formula in cells: (this in `A2` then simply autofill to `G2` and thenn everything down) (you'll get a row with 0's between the sheets, which can be filtered out or deleted later (copy/paste values))

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A$1,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SList,COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,0)+2)&"'!$A:$G"),$H2,0),"")
```

Set `H2` to 2 and for `H3`: (autofill down from `H3`)

```
=MAX(($H2+1)*($A2>0),2)
```

works perfectly for me [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_752Ga6Yb7uQ0ZPSGZ3aVNSRDg/view?usp=sharing)

No manual typing of sheetnames or something like that (only Column `H:H` as helper). Youll get rows's with 0's every time a new sheet is selected which can be filtered out. (or if you copy/paste values also can be deleted)

the `+2` at `...st,COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,0)+2)&...` simply tells to start with sheet 2 (if summary is the first). You may change it to `+1` if you want to lookup starting with the first sheet.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for so fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have all 100+ sheet names typed out in column A, this will work whether or not you have spaces in the sheet names:

```
=HLOOKUP("University", OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1,1,1,A2)),0,0,2,7),2,FALSE)
```